# Firebase Database, permission denied (No rules) swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to app programming. I finally got my app to work, but when I try to write data to firebase it gets denied?
I even set the rules to true so that anyone can read and write data.

I cant figure out what is wrong?

> 2017-09-12 10:52:26.584 Smart-app[3232]  [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] setValue: or removeValue: at /users failed: permission_denied

I am using this command to write data:

```
@IBAction func GemKunde(sender: UIButton) {
    ref?.child("users").setValue(["Fornavn": Fornavn.text!])
}
```

I have imported FirebaseDatabase and made a ref:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

My rules are:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Replace this Realtime Database Rules section in firebase</strike>

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users":{
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
    }
  } 
}
```

and Do not forget to click on publish button.

> **Note:** This heppens because of using the wrong configuration file `GoogleService-info.plist` Please check `DATABASE_URL`,other data and update your `GoogleService-info.plist`

<strike>Reference:https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/</strike>

Comment: Still says denied :(

Comment: your node is users or user?

Comment: Node? If im using multiple users? I am if thats it.

Comment: GoogleService-info.plist check DATABASE_URL?

Comment: The plist was the problem, I replaced it with an updated one from firebase. Thank you both for the help

Comment: This answer does now not match the solution to the original problem. @Yuyutsu Can you update your answer to reflect the actual problem: using the wrong configuration file.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have update my answer as per your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Go to Database.
Step 2. Select Realtime Database from the dropdown. (This cost me 4 hours)
Step 3. Change Rule

```
{  
    "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
   }
}
```

[image: Follow this instruction]

Comment: Thanks. That did it for me.